# Set default value after options have been bound

Tags: knockout.js

I think I might be doing it too early, on subscription of the array: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/gQ8zs/

javascript:

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.priceList = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPrice = ko.observable();
    self.defaultPrice = ko.observable();

    self.populatePriceList = function () {
        self.priceList([{
            Id: 1,
            NetPrice: 123,
            IsDefault: false
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            NetPrice: 123.99,
            IsDefault: true
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            NetPrice: 199.99,
            IsDefault: false
        }]);
    };
    self.priceList.subscribe(function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.priceList(), function (price) {
            if (price.IsDefault === true) {
                self.defaultPrice(price.NetPrice);
                self.selectedPrice(price);
            }
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

html:

```
<button data-bind="click: populatePriceList">Populate Price List</button>
<br />
<p data-bind="text: defaultPrice"></p>
<select data-bind="options: priceList, optionsText: 'NetPrice', value: selectedPrice"></select>
```

I expect the default value to be set as "123.99"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

priceList subscribe function called before updating dropdown.

Your should to use functions `walueWillMutate`/`valueHasMutated` to call subscriber after updating dropdown.

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.priceList = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPrice = ko.observable();
    self.defaultPrice = ko.observable();

    self.populatePriceList = function () {
        self.priceList.valueWillMutate();
        self.priceList([{
            Id: 1,
            NetPrice: 123,
            IsDefault: false
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            NetPrice: 123.99,
            IsDefault: true
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            NetPrice: 199.99,
            IsDefault: false
        }]);
        self.priceList.valueHasMutated();
    };

    self.priceList.subscribe(function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.priceList(), function (price) {
            if (price.IsDefault === true) {
                self.defaultPrice(price.NetPrice);
                self.selectedPrice(price);
            }
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/mSLZa/

you can do it with a helper function:

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.priceList = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPrice = ko.observable();
    self.defaultPrice = ko.observable();

    self.populatePriceList = function () {
        self.priceList([{
            Id: 1,
            NetPrice: 123,
            IsDefault: false
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            NetPrice: 123.99,
            IsDefault: true
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            NetPrice: 199.99,
            IsDefault: false
        }]);

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.priceList(), function (price) {
            if (price.IsDefault === true) {
                self.defaultPrice(price.NetPrice);
                self.selectedPrice(price);
            }
        })
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value after `applyBindings()` is not necessarily the right way to approach this.  The part where you iterate the array within a subscriber can be achieved more efficiently using `ko.computed`.  This also ensures that the default price will be maintained should the contents of the array change.  Here's how I would tackle the same problem.  The array can be set up front and the `defaultPrice` should be read-only.  Your view-model would look like this;

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;

    self.priceList = ko.observableArray([{
            Id: 1,
            NetPrice: 123,
            IsDefault: false
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            NetPrice: 123.99,
            IsDefault: true
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            NetPrice: 199.99,
            IsDefault: false
        }]);

    self.selectedPrice = ko.observable();
    self.defaultPrice = ko.computed(function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.priceList(), function (price) {
            if (price.IsDefault) {
                return price;
            }
        });
    });
};
```